# Using parity as Web3 provider running from a Docker container

Tags: web3js, parity, docker

I can't seem to be able to create a web3 (http) provider pointing to a parity node, running from a docker container.
I create a [repo](https://github.com/fbielejec/docker-web3/) which should reproduce the problem.

After running `docker-compose up` the parity starts, but the app fails:

```
Creating network "dockerweb3_net" with driver "bridge"
Attaching to qa_parity, qa_app
qa_parity | 2018-09-27 07:50:52 UTC Starting Parity-Ethereum/v2.0.6-stable-7658d22-20180921/x86_64-linux-gnu/rustc1.29.0
qa_parity | 2018-09-27 07:50:52 UTC Keys path /root/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum//keys/test
qa_parity | 2018-09-27 07:50:52 UTC DB path /root/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum//chains/test/db/ae90623718e47d66
qa_parity | 2018-09-27 07:50:52 UTC State DB configuration: fast
qa_parity | 2018-09-27 07:50:52 UTC Operating mode: active
qa_parity | 2018-09-27 07:50:52 UTC Configured for Ropsten using Ethash engine

qa_app    | /app/app.js:6
qa_app    |   throw "Can't connect to Ethereum node: qa_parity:8545";
```

Now if I get a shell to the failing container on the same docker network I can reach parity:

`docker run --net dockerweb3_net -it dockerweb3_app /bin/bash`

```
curl --data '{"method":"web3_clientVersion","params":[],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-X POST qa_parity:8545

> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"Parity-Ethereum//v2.0.6-stable-7658d22-20180921/x86_64-linux-gnu/rustc1.29.0","id":1}
```

Since **8545** is exposed, the parity is also reachable from the host (`http://localhost:8545`), so the problem must come from when [creating the provider](https://github.com/fbielejec/docker-web3/blob/master/app/app.js#L3).

Comment: Could you post your docker-compose.yaml file ?

Comment: It's in the repository that reproduces the problem: https://github.com/fbielejec/docker-web3/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like web3 simply requires a full path and not just the IP address. Connecting to the container and passing the url works:

```
env URL_PARITY="http://qa_parity:8545" node app.js
```